# Git equivalent of 'hg convert'

Tags: git, mercurial, mercurial-convert

There is a useful tool for Mercurial called the "[ConvertExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension)."  It allows you to essentially rewrite the entirety of a repository's history.  For example, if you have a file "foo.txt" in your root folder, but you want it to have been in the folder "root/bar/," you could use "hg convert" to change history to make it appear that it had always been in the "/bar/" folder.

Does an equivalent tool exist for git?

Answer (score 0):

[`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) is the equivalent.